# tkinter colorchooser hue, sat and lum values

Tags: colors, tkinter

The tkinter `colorchooser` dialogue box displays the `RGB` values and the `Hue`, `Sat` and `Lum` values, but returns only the RGB tuple and the hex color number.

Is there a way to capture the Hue, Lum and Sat values?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to automatically get anything other than RGB. There are known algorithms to convert from RGB to other forms.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look for them.